# Best method for trasmitting multiple video feeds at once via Bluetooth or WiFi?

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, video, signal-processing

If I want to transmit several video feeds via Bluetooth or WiFi what would be the best method to do so in order to save on bandwidth, increase speed, and maintain quality?

I wanted to know what is the best method for doing so when using a microcontroller on a builtin PCB, not a PC.

Comment: Sending several video feeds via BT or WiFi is one thing but trying to save on bandwidth whilst increasing speed and maintaining quality is obscuring things a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You could transmit video as [transport stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) which is a common format used in [DVB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Video_Broadcasting).

If you want to use a microcontroller, you should know that you need a powerful one, maybe some development board with an Embedded Linux operating system. Ready made devices that do that are used by DTH and DVB-T providers to uplink data to satellite transponders or terrestrial multiplexes. But this "muxers" provide raw data at their output which must be fed to a PSK or OFDM modulator then to a transmitter.

> save on bandwidth, increase speed, and maintain quality

1. Speed depends on connection (link) speed for example 24 MBit/s for Bluetooth 3.0 or 54 MBit/s for WiFi. It is comparable with the bandwith of a satellite DVB-S transponder at a Symbol Rate of 22000 MS/s (30-40 MBits/s).
2. Bandwidth and quality depend on the codec (for example MPEG-4 is better than MPEG-2)

If you want to try with a PC, you could use VLC and connect with another device over WiFi.